# Permanently set process limit

Tags: process, ulimit, resource-limiting

How do you permanently set process limit per user (`ulimit -u`) in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` and configure `nprocs` appropriately.

You may need to add `pam_limits` to your pam configuration.  The default configuration has pam_limits configured for many services.   You may want to add pam_limits to `/etc/pam.d/common-session`.

Comment: I think you may need to make some changes in /etc/pam.d as well.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure the PAM changes are still required, but they used to be -- was trying to grok some related bug reports, but it'd be easier to test it, I think.

Comment: @jgbelacqua:  They are there for all the common login methods (login, sum sudo, and *dm) methods as well as cron methods for 10.4 and 10.10.

Comment: A better description of this solution here: http://askubuntu.com/a/162230/119284

Answer (score 8):

Edit `/etc/security/limits.conf`, making changes per the examples and for the limits you want.

You'll also need to add a line to the `/etc/pam.d/common-session` file:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

The change to PAM modules may be necessary elsewhere, but generally, `common-session` is included related configurations, e.g.,

```
$ grep common-session /etc/pam.d/sshd :     

   sshd:@include common-session
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll vote up your answer when I get enought points :)