# Is it normal for thousands of files to be opened by Ubuntu programs?

Tags: files, lsof

Having used `lsof`, as suggested in [Too many open files - how to find the culprit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181215/too-many-open-files-how-to-find-the-culprit) , I've found that thousands of files are open due to operating-system style programs such as `unity-2d-`, `gnome-do`, and `nautilus`. Only one of the top 50 is an application-style program (firefox).

```
lsof | perl -lane '$x{"$F[0]:$F[1]"}++;
END { print "$x{$_}\t$_" for sort {$x{$a}<=>$x{$b}} keys %x}' | tail -50

lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /var/lib/lightdm/.gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
216 unity-2d-:26285
216 unity-2d-:31600
216 unity-2d-:2577
239 nautilus:30626
239 nautilus:3777
239 nautilus:31250
239 nautilus:30781
239 nautilus:15101
241 nautilus:26123
241 nautilus:20495
241 nautilus:9627
241 nautilus:31612
241 nautilus:26298
243 nautilus:7672
243 nautilus:603
243 nautilus:21594
243 nautilus:2590
243 nautilus:17574
243 firefox:9768
243 nautilus:12422
247 nautilus:14265
256 gnome-do:31632
256 gnome-do:20519
256 gnome-do:26318
256 gnome-do:9647
256 gnome-do:26143
257 gnome-do:12437
257 gnome-do:14284
257 gnome-do:21612
257 gnome-do:622
257 gnome-do:7686
257 gnome-do:2608
257 gnome-do:17603
270 unity-2d-:3756
270 unity-2d-:30612
272 unity-2d-:15087
277 unity-2d-:12408
277 unity-2d-:21580
278 unity-2d-:2576
278 unity-2d-:14251
278 unity-2d-:587
279 unity-2d-:9613
279 unity-2d-:30768
279 unity-2d-:20481
280 unity-2d-:26109
281 unity-2d-:26284
283 unity-2d-:31599
284 unity-2d-:31235
288 unity-2d-:7658
290 unity-2d-:17559
```

Is this normal, or is something wrong?

Comment: Another, clearer old-style Unix way: `lsof | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, This is normal. An Operating system can have thousands of files open simultaneously at any moment.  For example, at this moment, my system has 5858 files opened.

```
$ lsof | wc -l
5858
```

Please note that, `lsof` by default list all files opened by ***all processes***. So, if a file is accessed by two different processes, there will be two distinct instance in lsof output.

Also take note, the file are not all regular files. [lsof manual is saying](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/lsof.8.html)

> An  open file may be a regular file, a directory, a block special file,
>          a character special file, an executing text  reference,  a  library,  a
>          stream  or  a  network  file  (Internet socket, NFS file or UNIX domain
>          socket.)  A specific file or all the files in  a  file  system  may  be
>          selected by path.

But there is a subtle difference in *open files* and *open file descriptors*. See [this article](http://www.netadmintools.com/art295.html) to read this interesting topic. The important point is

> **What is an open file?**
>
> An open file is a file that is being used, or is it an open file descriptor? A file descriptor is a data structure used by a program to get a handle on a file, the most well known being 0,1,2 for standard in, standard out, and standard error. The file-max kernel parameter refers to open file descriptors, and file-nr gives us the current number of open file descriptors. But lsof lists all open files, including files which are not using file descriptors - such as current working directories, memory mapped library files, and executable text files. To illustrate, let's examine the difference between the output of lsof for a given pid and the file descriptors listed for that pid in /proc.

Also take a look at these links

- [How do I change the number of open files limit in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux)
- [How many open files](http://www.netadmintools.com/art295.html)
- [Ports and File descriptors](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Ports-and-File-Descriptors.html)

Comment: FWIW, mine has 91817 open.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm WOW! I have only Firefox and a terminal opened. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, you got me beat by 10 times there bud!

Comment: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr` gives me `90752 0 4883774`, which is pretty close to what I get with `lsof` (now 91923).

Comment: @AndrewGrimm , if you are still concerned that 91817 is still too many… I have 104596 open (with 8 GUI applications open on KDE).