# tail: inotify cannot be used, reverting to polling: Too many open files

Tags: bash, apache2, tomcat, sshd, tail

When I try to `tail -f catalina.out`, I get the error:

```
tail: inotify cannot be used, reverting to polling: Too many open files
```

I tried the answer in this post:
[Too many open files - how to find the culprit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181215/too-many-open-files-how-to-find-the-culprit/)

```
lsof | awk '{ print $2; }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
```

When I ran the above command, the output was

```
17 6115

13 6413

10 6417

10 6415

9 6418

9 6416

9 6414

8 6419

4 9 

4 8
```

I don't see any process having 1024 files open. Isn't the number of files open 17,13,10,10,9? Or am I understanding it wrong? And all these were bash,sshd,apache2, tomcat had number 4.

I also did `lsof | grep tail | wc -l` 
which returned `20`.
These numbers aren't huge, so why does `tail -f catalina.out` fail?

Answer (score 27):

This was solved for me by following the instructions on http://peter-butkovic.blogspot.com/2013/08/tail-inotify-resources-exhausted.html

Permanent solution (preserved across restarts)
Adding line:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576
```

to:

```
/etc/sysctl.conf
```

fixed the limit value permanently (even between restarts).

then do a

```
sysctl -p
```

Comment: Increasing file descriptors doesn't help me. My `tail` message was slightly different: `tail: inotify resources exhausted`.

This answer helped me.

You can also use `sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576 && sysctl -p` to test if it helps without permanently modifying it.

This post also helps https://nefaria.com/2014/08/tail-inotify-resources-exhausted/

Comment: In my case, I also had to add `fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1048576`

Answer (score 14):

I think [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/181408/147044) is not complete (it doesn't say anything about the maximum limit of files open on the system).

There are two limits regarding the maximum number of open files:

1. Maximum limit of files open *per process*.

   - You can see which is the value of this limit using: `ulimit -n`
   - You can change this limit using: `ulimit -n new_limit_number`
   - Here is a command to get the top 10 processes having many files open:

     ```
     lsof | awk '{ print $2; }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
     ```
2. Maximum limit of files open *per system*.

   - You can see which is the value of this limit using: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`
   - You can change this limit using: `echo new_limit_number > /proc/sys/fs/file-max`
   - Count all open file handles: `lsof | wc -l`

Answer (score 9):

`sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances` would get limit per user for `inotify`.

I experienced it, and all limit system wide were high enough, but setting by user are usually relatively low by default, you can increase it in `sysctl.conf` and reload it whit `sysctl -p`.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely, you've run out of your `inotify` watches. Probably, you're running some file synchronization tools(eg. Dropbox) in background?

In Linux, the internal implementation of `tail -f` command uses the `inotify` mechanism by default, so as to monitor file changes. If you've run out of all the `inotify` watches(8192 by default), then `inotify -f` have to switch to polling to detect changes to that file.

Of course, you can modify the maximum number of `inotify` watches.

reference:
http://www.quora.com/How-is-tail-f-implemented
http://peter-butkovic.blogspot.com/2013/08/tail-inotify-resources-exhausted.html
https://serverfault.com/questions/510708/tail-inotify-cannot-be-used-reverting-to-polling-too-many-open-files

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
ps aux | grep tail
```

to check if too many tail command running, such as a spawn by crontab.

Comment: ha this actually worked, tailing way too many files

Comment: How do I translate the data? Can you explain what each piece of information means and what to do about it? For example: `root     20161  0.0  0.0  11132  1044 pts/0    S+   17:27   0:00 grep tail`

Comment: It is a problem only if TOO MANY processes matched, the line matched contain
"grep" is generated by the command itself. Please use "pgrep tail" command
instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check your kernel version, it might be this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1101666

Answer (score 0):

edit /etc/sysctl.conf add

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576
fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1048576
```

```
sysctl -p
```