# sysctl: permission denied on key 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches'

Tags: 16.04, server, inotify

I have a  **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab127.2 x86_64) VPS**
I am getting the following error while running my rails application

> FATAL: Listen error: unable to monitor directories for changes. Visit
>   https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers
>   for info on how to fix this.

I'm trying to fix that by increasing the watch limit by

```
  $ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
  $ sudo sysctl -p
```

it is throwing another error as

> sysctl: permission denied on key 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches'

I have root access to the server.

Any Help to increase the limit is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That may be a limitation of the VPS - see for example [Permission denied when setting values in sysctl on Ubuntu 12.04](https://serverfault.com/questions/545666/permission-denied-when-setting-values-in-sysctl-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: @steeldriver 100% it is a limitation of the VPS.

Comment: I was bumping up against this error and my problems was that I was including the "$" on my cut/paste of the command - so instead of running 'sudo sysctl -p' I was running '$sudo sysctl -p' - stupid error on my part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any Help to increase the limit is highly appreciated.

Not going to happen by either you or anyone on Askubuntu.

> VPS

Take this up with the company hosting the VPS. They do not allow you to change any of those parameters. You are working in a virtual container and those changes to sysctl will affect everyone on that system, not just your container.

Answer (score 0):

"Increasing file descriptors doesn't help me. My tail message was slightly different: tail: inotify resources exhausted. This answer helped me. You can also use sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576 && sysctl -p to test if it helps without permanently modifying it. This post also helps nefaria.com/2014/08/tail-inotify-resources-exhausted – djxak Oct 2 '17 at 18:27" djxak comment on [tail: inotify cannot be used, reverting to polling: Too many open files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299689)
I have the same restrictions so I think this worked for me because is a temporal solution:

sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576 && sysctl -p