# Why my Ubuntu Software isn't opening?

Tags: 16.04, software-center

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. In my computer i can't open Ubuntu Software. I tried to reboot my computer several times but it still doesn't open. I tried to open it from terminal but it shows 
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G26Pw.png)

What should i do? Please help me.

Comment: If you'd [search for the error message](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=Too+many+open+files), you would find many answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error log, you're getting lots of "Too many open files" errors. This means you've got a process running somewhere which has lots of files open, and you have hit your 'open files limit'.
To increase the size of your open files limit, you can follow [these instructions](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/).

If you want to try and diagnose which process has so many files open at that time, you should analyse the output of `lsof`. This command might help narrow down which processes could be causing your problem:
`lsof | awk '{ print $2 " " $1; }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -20`
[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/181408/638008)

EDIT: If the above does not fix your problem, running:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-software -f
```

may also help

Comment: I would strongly suggest the diagnosing part. That's not common to happen to the standard Ubuntu user, especially not directly after restart. It happens to me when running some webapps with tomcat (namely geoserver).