# Unable to debug Too Many Open Processes from lsof

Tags: lsof

I followed the instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181215/too-many-open-files-how-to-find-the-culprit), but my lsof file is 56,000 lines long. I tried opening it to figure out which process is creating so much noise, but it looks like gibberish to me.

[image]

How do I figure out which process is the problem?

Comment: OK, well mine is ~36k long currently.  What is the problem you are having that leads you to be counting lines of output from lsof? Did you by any chance try raising the limit as described in the question you linked?

Comment: I didn't know what a normal amount of processes was. It seemed too big, but I didn't have the knowldge to judge.  It was a rabbit trail, but the error eventually led me to the real culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I was being affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1646419). The processes error occurred while launching the software center. Running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software -f` resolved my core issue.