# Ubuntu failed to launch XXX - too many open files

Tags: 16.04, gnome, files, ulimit

I just freshly installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.4 a day ago and now I sometimes have trouble opening any application on my machine. When I try to open an application a notification pops up with

> Ubuntu failed to launch $application, too many open files

As this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/181408/253889) suggests, I tried looking for the process the opens to many files by running

```
lsof | awk '{ print $2 " " $1; }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -20
```

which resulted in following output

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tracefs file system /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
  Output information may be incomplete.
 5472 3100 JS\x20Hel
 4004 20115 TaskSched
 3792 3158 JS\x20Hel
 3192 3100 mozStorag
 3048 20990 JS\x20Hel
 2892 23218 JS\x20Hel
 2808 21566 JS\x20Hel
 2212 3158 ImgDecode
 1896 3158 StyleThre
 1824 3100 ImgDecode
 1824 3100 FS\x20Bro
 1824 3100 DOM\x20Wo
 1778 20990 ImgDecode
 1687 23218 ImgDecode
 1638 21566 ImgDecode
 1524 20990 StyleThre
 1446 23218 StyleThre
 1404 21566 StyleThre
 1368 3100 DNS\x20Re
 1368 3100 DataStora
```

can anybody tell me how I fix this error or how to find the cause of the problem? I tried to find out what JS\x20Hel is but I didn't find anything regarding this.

If any further info is needed to answer this question let me know and I'll happily supply.

Comment: I also started to monitor PID 3100 with ```lsof -p 3100 -r 1800 > lsof.out``` as suggested [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21067352)

Comment: What does `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` reveal?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` gives me `792497`

Comment: My system has about the same number and I've never run into a problem. Hopefully someone who has ran into a problem stumbles across this question.

Comment: for some reason this problem hasnt occured anymore in the last few days

Comment: Alls well that ends well.