# Got error dbus: Failed to determine seats of user "1000": Too many open files - why and how to fix?

Tags: dbus

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS with all updates installed.

Currently I see strange behavior: I can't start new GTK applications and Qt ones.

For GTK-based applications I get:

```
$ atril file.pdf
Failed to get bus connection: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.LimitsExceeded: Failed to determine seats of user "1000": Too many open files
```

For Qt-based applications I get:

```
$ konsole
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
KUniqueApplication: Cannot find the D-Bus session server:  "Failed to determine seats of user \"1000\": Too many open files" 

KUniqueApplication: Pipe closed unexpectedly.
```

I cant guess why this happens.

Comment: Is https://askubuntu.com/questions/181215/too-many-open-files-how-to-find-the-culprit of any help?