# Open file limit

Tags: ulimit

I'm trying to increase open file limit in Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS.
Followed information posted in this question: [How do I increase the open files limit for a non-root user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user)

- Added to `/etc/sysctl.conf` following line: `fs.file-max=500000`
- Added to `/etc/security/limits.conf` following lines:

  `*               soft    nofile          10000`

  `*               hard    nofile          10000`
- Added to `/etc/pam.d/common-session` (My system do not have any other files prefixed with common-session at /etc/pam.d/) following line: `session required        pam_limits.so`
- Did system restart

But the value of open file limit is still same 1024:

```
# ulimit -n
1024
# cat /proc/{PID}/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max open files            1024                 1024                 files

# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
500000

# sysctl fs.file-max
fs.file-max = 500000
```

What I'm doing wrong and how to increase open file limit?

Comment: We do not support Ubuntu versions that are end of life. Upgrade to 14.04 please.

Comment: ...also, Ubuntu 8.04 [went EOL last year](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_life).

Comment: I understand that this version of Ubuntu is old but right now I can not upgrade it.

Comment: I understand that you want to ride your horse, but it's been dead for more than a year.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the maximum number of open files by setting a new value in kernel variable /proc/sys/fs/file-max as follows (login as the root):

```
sysctl -w fs.file-max=500000
```

Above command forces the limit to 500000 files. You need to edit /etc/sysctl.conf file and put following line so that after reboot the setting will remain as it is:

```
vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Append a config directive as follows:

> fs.file-max = 500000

Save and close the file.

Users need to log out and log back in again to changes take effect or just type the following command:

```
sysctl -p
```

Verify your settings with command:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

OR

```
sysctl fs.file-max
```

[Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/)

Comment: I now get for ulimit -u 31534 is it ok? why isn't it 500000?