# Google Chrome Tabs Crash

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome version 36.0.1985.143
Ubuntu 14.04

After upgrading to 14.04 Google Chromes tabs crash. I'm not sure of the conditions on how to make them crash. But after idk a few hours or a day of using Chrome or after I restart Chrome I'll go to open a new tab and it just crashes. Even when it's just an empty tab.

It seems to do it maybe based on the amount of resources the page uses? For example if I try to open the Google play store site, the tab crashes (right now). If I go to just google.com the page works. I could open another site and it loads, but when I try to scroll down it crashes.

I have about 41 tabs open in 4 different windows. I've tried turning off all plug-ins and apps as the crash page suggests but with no luck.

I'm on a Dell Latitude E6530 8gb of ram. Only 40% of my ram is being used.

---

I uninstalled, deleted any files/folders left behind, then reinstalled Chrome as @klyn suggested. So far I have not had a crash.

Edit 08/09/2014:
Nope I was wrong. It's still doing it. I have no idea what is happening. The page might partial load them bam, it crashes. I try to open an new tab, it crashes. And this is a new tab with nothing on it, Chrome's default tab page. The crash is the "Aw, snap!" crash. The page will sometimes load, then I scroll down and it crashes.

If I had to guess, it would have to do with the amount of tabs I have open.

I'll try @Matthew Greenlaw's solution and report back.

---

Looks like @Matthew Greenlaw's issue is the same one I'm having. Here's what came up in the error logs

```
[28578:28610:0913/140212:WARNING:shared_memory_posix.cc(386)] Shared memory creation failed; out of file descriptors
[28578:28610:0913/140212:ERROR:host_shared_bitmap_manager.cc(144)] Cannot create shared memory buffer
[28578:28613:0913/140212:WARNING:crash_handler_host_linux.cc(289)] Could not translate tid - assuming crashing thread is thread group leader; syscall_supported=0
[28578:28630:0913/140212:ERROR:crash_handler_host_linux.cc(371)] Failed to write crash dump for pid 28739
Cannot upload crash dump: failed to open
Failed to create temporary file in /tmp: cannot upload crash dump
```

I've upped my file limit to 4096. I'll report back in a couple weeks if the crash hasn't happened again, and mark @Matthew Greenlaw's answer as the answer.

---

@Matthew Greenlaw's fix worked. Still no issues.

Comment: have you tried to just re install it yet?

Comment: I reinstalled and it seems to work now. I haven't had any crashes.

Comment: Questions reporting bugs are considered off-topic for our site (see [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions)). This should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). You can [make Apport collect and submit the necessary technical information](http://askubuntu.com/a/244982/22949)--but still make sure to read the [bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) first, and describe the problem thoroughly in the bug report you write in the web browser (which will come up automatically after Apport sends the data).

Comment: If this is a file limit issue then it's not a bug. I've upped my file limit to 4096. If the tab crash hasn't happened again in two weeks I will report back that it is a file limit issue. If there's a tab crash again then I will move this thread to a bug report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try running Google Chrome from the terminal with debugging enabled. You can do that using this command `google-chrome --enable-logging=stderr`. Use Chrome until you have a crash and then look over the terminal to see what sort of errors you see on crash.

In my case, I had the same exact issue with Chrome crashing when a new tab was opened. It was being caused by Google Chrome exceeding the limit of files that my user was allowed to have open at one time. Here is a [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user) to a askubuntu post where you will learn how to change ulimit in the `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

After you make changes, make sure you log out and then log back in for them to take effect.

Comment: Note: make sure all chrome processes are killed before trying to run chrome from the command line. If you don't Chrome will just attach itself to the already running Chrome. Even just closing all browsers does not kill all Chrome processes. I had to run for i in $(ps x | grep chrome | cut -d"?" -f1 | grep -v chrome); do kill -9 $i ; done to make sure they were all dead.

Comment: More error output, just for searchability:

[2164:2205:1017/121050:ERROR:socket_libevent.cc(79)] CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error, errno=24: Too many open files
[2164:2202:1017/121050:ERROR:shared_memory_posix.cc(231)] Creating shared memory in /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.UUNmxy failed: Too many open files
[2164:2202:1017/121050:ERROR:host_shared_bitmap_manager.cc(144)] Cannot create shared memory buffer

Comment: Cross-posting this link, which has some workaround info I wrote up: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333996