# sudo can't give ulimit command?

Tags: permissions, sudo, bug-reporting, ulimit

I am trying to write a solution for another user, when I noticed that sudo ulimit -c returns command not found. So then I tried this:

```
$ sudo ulimit -c
  sudo: ulimit: command not found

$ ulimit -c
0

$ sudo -i
# ulimit -c
0
```

so... it works from root, and it works with out sudo, but not with sudo. Is this a bug?

Comment: ulimit isn't a command as such, it's a bash builtin.  Try: `sudo bash -c ulimit`

Comment: Related: [Why ulimit doesn't work when run with sudo?](https://superuser.com/q/396102/87805)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ulimit` is a shell built-in command like `cd`
you can't use like:

```
sudo cd /test/
```

similarly you can't use

```
sudo ulimit -c
```

This is not a separate program. `sudo` looks for a binary to run, but there is no `ulimit` binary.

If you want to change  your limit  then you can define limits in `limits.conf` file. Those limits are defined in `/etc/security/limits.conf` or `/etc/security/limits.d/`.
you can take help from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user)

or

use shell like:

```
sudo sh -c "ulimit -c"
sudo bash -c "ulimit -c"
sudo bash -c ulimit 
sudo sh -c "ulimit -n"
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a bug?

No.  `sudo` has no knowledge of commands that are built in to the various shells, like `ulimit` and `cd`.

You've been presented with two ways of addressing this — using a shell as an intermediary and adjusting the limits elsewhere than on the command line itself.  Here is a third, for the situations when one is trying to use such commands to make modifications to process state rather than to display it.

If one could run the shell builtins as `sudo ulimit …` or `sudo cd …` to actually modify process state, that would not be particularly useful.  That would run nothing else afterwards, in the process whose limits or working directory had been changed.  One would adjust process limits or working directory only to immediately exit the process.

**But** there are toolsets with chain-loading external commands with these functions.  They do the same thing as the shell builtins but *also* chain load to *another* program after they have done so.

They are [the various daemontools-family toolsets](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/daemontools-family.html) — daemontools, daemontools-encore, nosh, perp, s6, freedt, and runit.

The tools for setting limits and then chain loading to another program are variously [`softlimit`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/softlimit.html) (daemontools), `softlimit` (freedt), [`softlimit`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/softlimit.8.html) (daemontools-encore) [`softlimit`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/softlimit.html) (nosh), [`s6-softlimit`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-softlimit.html) (s6), [`chpst`](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html) (runit), and [`runlimit`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=runlimit.8) (perp).  So one could run, say, vim with an altered core file size limit using daemontools, daemontools-encore, nosh, or freedt with the command:

```
sudo softlimit -c 0 vim
```

nosh also has a similar [`ulimit`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/ulimit.html) command that uses different unit sizes for the various limits to the ones used with `softlimit`:

```
sudo ulimit -c 0 vim
```

The same goes for changing directory, for which there are the nosh [`chdir`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/chdir.html) external chain-loading command:

```
sudo chdir /etc vim rc.local
```

and the [`cd`](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/cd.html) external command from [execline](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/index.html):

```
sudo /command/cd /etc vim rc.local
```