# Can't set max limit of opened files

Tags: ulimit

I use Ubuntu 15.10 (64bit). I tried to run `ulimit -n 102400`, but after `reboot` or relogging (log out and log in) and excuting `ulimit -n` I see: `1024`. I tried adding

```
* soft nofile 102400
* hard nofile 102400
```

to `/etc/security/limits.conf` but as I said before, I still get `1024`. How can I change the max limit of opened files?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to edit `/etc/pam.d/common-session`* and add the following line to the end:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

Then reboot.

Saw that solution from [How do I increase the open files limit for a non-root user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user), it worked for me. I'm on Ubuntu 15.10.