# MySQL failed to restart on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I'm trying to restart MySQL after saving a script. The error states

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When running `systemctl status mysql.service` here's what I get:

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Isn 2016-09-26 17:15:28 MYT; 17s ago
  Process: 17478 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 17474 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 17478 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 17479 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─17479 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─17516 sleep 1
```

I'm not sure where to start fixing this.

This is the script I saved prior to restarting mysql:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_rollback_on_timeout=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=600
max_connections=350
log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog-format = 'ROW'
```

Running `journalctl -xe | tail -20` gives me this:

```
Sep 26 17:46:29 guest mysqld[21937]: 2016-09-26T09:46:29.037709Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
Sep 26 17:46:29 guest mysqld[21937]: 2016-09-26T09:46:29.037798Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_connections: 214 (requested 350)
Sep 26 17:46:29 guest mysqld[21937]: 2016-09-26T09:46:29.037809Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 400 (requested 2000)
Sep 26 17:46:29 guest mysqld[21937]: 2016-09-26T09:46:29.187886Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
Sep 26 17:46:29 guest mysqld[21937]: 2016-09-26T09:46:29.189296Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log) starting as process 21937 ...
Sep 26 17:46:29 guest mysqld[21937]: 2016-09-26T09:46:29.191216Z 0 [ERROR] You have enabled the binary log, but you haven't provided the mandatory server-id. Please refer to the proper server start-up parameters documentation
Sep 26 17:46:29 guest mysqld[21937]: 2016-09-26T09:46:29.191242Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Sep 26 17:46:29 guest mysqld[21937]: 2016-09-26T09:46:29.191255Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
Sep 26 17:46:29 guest mysqld[21937]: 2016-09-26T09:46:29.191300Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Sep 26 17:46:29 guest systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 26 17:46:32 guest NetworkManager[878]: <info>  [1474883192.2910] device (eth0): Lowering IPv6 MTU (9000) to match device MTU (1500)
```

Running `ulimit && ulimit -Sa` gives me:

```
unlimited
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 128071
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 128071
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Can you append the output of `journalctl -xe | tail -50` to your question?

Comment: @L.D.James the whole output? It's pretty large. Or is it just the last few bits?

Comment: The output will be 50 lines.  Actually 15 or 20 lines should suffice.  You can change the `-50` to `-15`.  I just wanted to be sure to include the line where the actually problem is occurring.

Comment: @L.D.James I see, so that's what the tail command is for. I've added a `journalctl -xe | tail -20` output.

Comment: Can you append the output of `ulimit && ulimit -Sa` to your question.  You might have to copy and paste the commandline to get it right.

Comment: @L.D.James Also added, is it a resource problem?

Comment: It, indeed, is.  I'm wondering why the `guest` is included in the journalctl line.  Also, what is causing the high resource demand.

Comment: @L.D.James guest is actually the name of the user, it's a lab desktop and I'll only be using it for 4 months so couldn't be bothered to change the name. Not sure about the high demands either. I'm only running the terminal and a browser.

Comment: What about the "ERROR: You have enabled the binary log..." message? Did you intend to do that? MySQL expects a server id there, which I only know from master-slave setups.

Comment: @Edd Please test my answer provided and let me know if you're still having problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Fatal Error:**

MYQL is failing to start because as the Journalctl output indicates, `but you haven't provided the mandatory server-id.`  Add the mandatory id as indicated in the code below.

`/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
Change from:

```
log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog-format = 'ROW'
```

Change to:

```
server-id=master-01
log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog-format = 'ROW'
```

This will get your server running while you address the proper formatting of your desired logging.

**non-fatal warnings:**

For the open files limit of your error you will have to either decrease the demand in the configuration you edited or increase the system's limits with:

`/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
* soft nofile [new number]
* hard nofile [new number]
```

The first column describes WHO the limit is to apply for. '*' is a wildcard, meaning all users. To raise the limits for root, you have to explicitly enter 'root' instead of '*'.

Taken from:
https://askubuntu.com/a/162230/29012

Comment: Worked! Is it because of explicitly stating it's the master device? I tried putting in `server-id = 1` before this but it didn't work.

Comment: in which file these things should change?

Comment: For the `mysql` configuration edit `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.  For the system's `open files limit` look at: `/etc/security/limits.conf `.  I'll update my answer with this information a little later.  Can you let me know if your issue becomes resolved?  This way I can include any other pertinent information in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Got the same error, but in my case simply the disk was full. Make also sure to check this.

```
df -h --total
```

Comment: +1 This was it for me. Free up some space and start the service.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the issue by:

1. Adding Swapfile
2. Adding `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20M` to configuration file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` making sure it is in a group

Answer (score 0):

My problem is the host's IP is changed.

So edit the `bind-address` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to the correct one.