# My ubuntu 16.04 freezes randomly (too many open files: dconf will not work properly)

Tags: 16.04, files, freeze

This is a fresh install on an Atom PC. Everything I am trying is functional, except that the machine freezes randomly (after few min or few hours). So far it happened while I was doing something on the UI (i.e. move the mouse or type).
Once it freezes, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> does NOT work. Neither does <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysReq</kbd>.

I see some suspicious logs on `/var/logs/syslog`, not sure if they are related:

```
Dec 26 14:55:06 eval1 gnome-session[1516]: (gnome-software:1676): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user': Too many open files.  dconf will not work properly.
Dec 26 14:55:06 eval1 gnome-session[1516]: (gnome-software:1676): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user': Too many open files.  dconf will not work properly.
Dec 26 14:55:06 eval1 gnome-session[1516]: (gnome-software:1676): Gs-WARNING **: failed to call gs_plugin_refresh on fwupd: Too many open files
Dec 26 14:55:06 eval1 gnome-session[1516]: (gnome-software:1676): GLib-ERROR **: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files
Dec 26 14:55:06 eval1 kernel: [   78.554259] do_trap: 36 callbacks suppressed
Dec 26 14:55:06 eval1 kernel: [   78.554267] traps: pool[2147] trap int3 ip:7f330b187a6b sp:7f32e3ffe6f0 error:0
Dec 26 14:55:56 eval1 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 108...
```

Any idea what to look for?

Comment: Related? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user

Comment: Yes looks like he is hitting open file limit like @ByteCommander linked, anyway i'll suggest checking why are you hitting that limit (maybe with `lsof`).