# How do I increase number of open files with ulimit on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, ulimit

When I try to `ulimit -n 4097` or greater I get the following error:

```
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

None of the solutions at [How do I increase the open files limit for a non-root user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user) seem to work or apply.

I can raise the limit to 4096 but not beyond.

Output of `ulimit -n -H
4096`

**Edit**:

Problem solved:

https://superuser.com/questions/1200539/cannot-increase-open-file-limit-past-4096-ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried  `sudo` ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. What's the output of `ulimit -n -H`? Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))