# On Ubuntu 22.04, editing limits.conf to increase number of file descriptors doesn't work

Tags: 22.04, files, settings, ulimit, resource-limiting

I followed this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/162230

I edit limits.conf, now it is

```
* soft nofile 65536
* hard nofile 65536
* soft nproc  65536
* hard nproc  Unlimited
root soft nofile 65536
root hard nofile 65536
```

Also, I edit both "/etc/pam.d/common-session" and "/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive". Add the line at the end of both files:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

And I restarted the Ubuntu, but "prlimit" still shows

```
NOFILE  ... 1024  65536 files
```

`ulimit -n` also shows 1024

How could I change this permanently?

Comment: After these commands, re-login or reboot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to change this is to put `ulimit -S -n 65536` in your shell init file (`.bashrc` possibly).