# set virtual memory limit permanently

Tags: ssh, configuration, etc

I need to keep my remote machine from swapping (will not respond to ssh anymore). Therefore I set `ulimit -Sv 300000; ulimit -Hv 300000`. It is laborious to do this manually, so I want to set it permanently.

In [Permanently set process limit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34557/permanently-set-process-limit)
it is suggested to set the parameter in etc/security/limits.conf.

However looking at the manpages
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/limits.conf.5.html

I can not find an entry for `virtual memory`.

How can I set the virtual memory limits for users permanently?

I am on `Ubuntu Version="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"`

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it?

Comment: There's "address space limit", and virtual memory is the addressable memory.

Comment: If all you need is to stop swapping, comment out the entry for the swap partition / file in `/etc/fstab` and reboot. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a better way, but I put `ulimit -v SIZE` in `.bash_profile`.